# How can I input exactly a five character string on a single line and then out put the string with spaces between each character? Java

Tags: java, string, input, printf, java.util.scanner

I want a user to input five letters on a single line (for example the word "hello") and have the output be "h e l l o". I am able to do this with `String.replace` (as seen below) **but I need to use `printf` and `%s` to do it**.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter five chatracters: ");
String charoutput = scanner.next();
String charoutput2 = charoutput.replace("", "       ");

System.out.println("You have entered: " +charoutput2);
```

Comment: Loop through the `String` and print `charAt(i) + “ “`

Comment: http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/displaying-text-using-printf-method

Comment: Yes Steve, that does work, however I need to use printf and like %10s for ten spaces instead of brute force spacing

Comment: TIL that you could do `.replace(""..` with an empty string. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` to print space for each character in string

```
String str = "hello";
    char[] ch =str.toCharArray();
    for (char c:ch) {
        System.out.printf("%2s", c);  // h e l l o
    }
```

or you can use Java 8 streams to do it in line

```
Arrays.stream(str.split("")).forEach(i->System.out.printf("%2s",i)); //h e l l o
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot

Comment: It may be good to note that this prints " h e l l o", with a leading space before the 'h' as well.

Comment: yes it applies for each character in string, we can do it in a way if it is mandatory not to append space before 1st character

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

Using `String.join`:

```
String input = "Hello";
String result = String.join(" ", input.split(""));
// result now holds "H e l l o"
```

Using regex with replaceAll:

```
String input = "Hello";
String result = input.replaceAll(".","$0 ").trim();
// result now holds "H e l l o"
```

Using a loop:

```
String input = "Hello";
int length = input.length;
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
  System.out.printf("%c%s", input.charAt(i), i<length ? " " : "");
// outputs "H e l l o"
```

Using `printf`:

```
String input = "Hello";
for(char c : input.toCharArray())
  System.out.printf("%2c", c);
// outputs " H e l l o" (NOTE the leading space!)
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##hZBRT8IwFIXf@RU3jSRdwAZ5FIkhvmiiT8Qn40OtBTpLu7R3KDH89nm3jgWD4Mu67Z7znXOby428zN8/qkpZGSM8SeO@ewBF@WaNgogS6dh48w5rGvE5BuOWL68gs1oGkBNAlGismCvpnA4Q23MKTn8ez/l8G1GvhXHZpCEkJBhXlEim1i6c/sJH4zTfy5LNlygKMqB1nD3UnmtgMEh2kh4ig46lxSuCNlMRdGGl0jNrORNsyC5GwDJB2vW5kOeYWHtvymvZfyaOKTH9ELmnS2PAhm2FWFiDnLHs38ADwGHiuDU2DzKA1W6Jq27H9Hlqnz1cgvW@IG6rW/jAa5iZjiZgbhKE3gaDrJkfkxac9VU/douplQwz5CYbdn64pd4MKIWd3ra7wBNNU9jvpnUWKAKnaPR3dXgIcsuzc33HiuqqBrTr7arqXlvrfwA)

My preference would be the `String.join`, since it's basically a builtin of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways you can do that:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter five chatracters: ");
String charOutput = scanner.next();

String separatedChars = "";
for(char c: charOutput.toCharArray()) {
    separatedChars += c + " ";
} 

System.out.printf("You have entered: %s", separatedChars);
```

Here you iterate through each char of the received string and add it to the `separatedChars` variable followed by a space. Then, the result is printed using **printf**.